# Haskell runs incredibly slow compared to C++

Tags: c++, performance, haskell

I have an assignment, that I need to solve in Haskell.
It was firstly solved in C++, then I rewrote the code to Haskell.
The algorithm is working correctly but the Haskell version runs slower, compared to the C++ version.
For example, for the input:

```
110110100011010101010101
010101101001000101010100
```

Haskell (with GHCI): 20 sec
Haskell (compiled GHC): 3 sec
C++: <1 sec
With a difference this much, I think, I am doing something wrong.
**Problem description**: We are given 2 arrays(strings) of the same length, containing 0s and 1s. Our task is to find the minimal switches(switch=0->1 or 1->0) to make the source array identical to the target. There is a rule for switching: We can only change the state of i if i+1 is 1 AND i+2->n are 0, except for the last one.

**C++ code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

//flips the i-th char int s to match the i-th char in t
int flip2(int i, string& s, char t){
    if(i>=s.length() || s[i]==t) return 0; //if matches, or non-existent index, returns 0 steps
    int c=1; // 1 step is switching the character
    c+=flip2(i+1,s,'1'); //in order to switch i, i+1 have to be 1
    for(int j=i+2;j<s.length();j++) //in order to switch i, i+2->n have to be 0
        c+=flip2(j,s,'0');
    s[i]=t;
    return c;
}

//returns the minimum number of switch steps to make s=t
int ultimateFlip( string s, string t){
    int c=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){ // switches every character in s to match t
        c+=flip2(i,s,t[i]); //adds up the steps
    }
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    string s; // source array (made up of 0s and 1s)
    getline(cin, s);
    string t; //target array (made up of 0s and 1s)
    getline(cin, t);

    cout<<ultimateFlip(s,t);
}
```

**Haskell code:**

```
import System.IO
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
    
    s <- getLine -- source string
    t <- getLine -- target string
     
    let sol = ultimateFlip s t
    
    putStrLn $ show sol
    return ()

--returns the minimum number of switch steps to make s=t
ultimateFlip :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Int
ultimateFlip [] [] = 0
ultimateFlip (s:sx) (t:tx) = k + ultimateFlip sxn tx
    where
        (k,sxn)=flip2 s t sx --snx = new (after) version of sx(the rest of the string)

--flips the s to match t, sx= rest of the source string after s
flip2 :: Char->Char->[Char]->(Int,[Char])
flip2 s t sx
    | s == t = (0,sx) --if mathes, no switch needed
    | null sx = (1,sx) --if last one, one switch need
    | otherwise = (k2+k1+1,'1':nsx2)
        where
            (sxh:sxt) = sx
            (k1,nsx1) = flip2 sxh '1' sxt --switch next to 1
            (k2,nsx2) = zeroOut nsx1 --switch everything after the next to 0

--switch everything to 0
zeroOut :: [Char] -> (Int, [Char])
zeroOut [] = (0,[])
zeroOut (s:sx) = (k1+k2,'0':nsx2)
    where
        (k1,nsx1) = flip2 s '0' sx
        (k2,nsx2) = zeroOut nsx1
```

For Haskell I am using: GHC, version 8.10.2
For C++ I am using: gcc (GCC) 10.2.0

Comment: "For Haskell I am using: GHCi, version 8.10.2" while I doubt you can ever get Haskell as fast as C/C++, at least not without specialised "tricks", this isn't comparing like with like. You need to actually compile your Haskell code, with optimisations, for this to be a fair comparison - not just run it with GHCi.

Comment: You should compile this with `ghc -O ...` to an executable. `ghci` is not designed to benchmark a function.

Comment: It would be helpful if you commented your code. But from what I see, indexing in Haskell will be much slower because it uses linked lists while C++ has random access for its strings. Try `Data.Vector` or properly explain what the functions should do, maybe there is more suitable algorithm for Haskell.

Comment: @Quimby, for what it's worth, this code doesn't seem to be doing any indexing.

Comment: @LouisWasserman The C++ is with `s[i]=t;` and there at least O(N^3) flips if I am counting correctly.

Comment: @DanielWagner I am not Haskell expert, but I think the indexing is hidden in the recursion through `flip2` returning a tuple, but not sure, I woul appreciate OP commenting on their code.

Comment: Well it would indeed be helpful if we know *what* problem we are currently solving, instead of *how* we are solving it right now.

Comment: Okay, following your advice, I actually compiled my program with GHC (ghc -dynamic main.hs). Now it has a much better run-time of 3 seconds, but it is still slower than the C++ counterpart. Is this a maximum, what I could expect from Haskell? Edit: I am working on the comments and the problem description

Comment: I updated the post with comments and a description of the problem. Now we should know both what we are solving and how we are solving it.

Comment: Note that you should also compile with `-O2` (i.e., `ghc -O2 main.hs`).  This should roughly halve the runtime compared to `ghc main.hs`.

Comment: @bontovicspal: the idea is typically that you should *not* translate imperative code to Haskell, just as with most tools/... there is a way to implement programs to get better results both in *quality* and performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are spending an awful lot of time allocating and immediately destructuring pairs. That's pretty unnecessary, because you always know what `[Char]` you're going to get back in the second half of the tuple. Here's one way to eliminate that problem:

```hs
ultimateFlip :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Int
ultimateFlip [] [] = 0
ultimateFlip (s:sx) (t:tx)
    | s == t = ultimateFlip sx tx
    | null sx = 1
    | otherwise = ultimateFlip sx tx' + 1 + ultimateFlip tx' tx where
        tx' = '1' : ('0'<$drop 1 tx)
```

With this change, the Haskell performs pretty much the same as the C++ on my machine -- sometimes a few ms faster, sometimes a few ms slower, for inputs slightly longer than the one you proposed.

Of course, as usual, switching to a better algorithm blows microoptimizations like this one out of the water in terms of gains. The following implementation takes less time than the reporting precision of `time` even for much longer strings.

```hs
import Data.Bits

main :: IO ()
main = do
    s <- getLine
    t <- getLine
    print (ultimateFlip s t)

ultimateFlip :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Int
ultimateFlip [] [] = 0
ultimateFlip (s:sx) (t:tx)
    | s == t = ultimateFlip sx tx
    | otherwise = go '1' pow sx + 1 + go '1' pow tx where
        pow = 2^(length sx-1)
        go _ _ [] = 0
        go s pow (t:tx) = go s' pow' tx + n where
            pow' = shiftR pow 1
            (s', n) = if s == t then ('0', 0) else ('1', pow)
```

It also smoothly upgrades to using arbitrary-sized integers for those longer inputs just by switching `Int` to `Integer` in the type signature of `ultimateFlip`.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem you're having is with a lack of "strictness".  Haskell's lazy evaluation means that even simple calculations like `k2+k1+1` generally won't be evaluated until the answer is needed.  With recursive functions performing a series of additions like thus, you can sometimes end up building an enormous unevaluated expression that takes up tons of memory before it finally gets evaluated at the end.

Here, by adding a language extension at the top:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
```

and adding a single strictness "!" annotation in your `flip`'s "where" clause:

```
(!k1,nsx1) = flip2 sxh '1' sxt
 ^
```

this drops the runtime on my machine from 800ms to 80ms (again, compiled with `ghc -O2`).  That's still slower than the C++ version (20ms), but it's in the right ballpark.

The annotation here has the effect of forcing the expression to be evaluated.  Figuring out where strictness annotations are needed is a bit of a dark art.  In this case, I suspected your counting was causing the problem, so I threw in "!" before all the places that a count was being returned, and then I deleted them until I found the one that made most of the difference.

The remaining speed difference is probably a result of using a lot of list processing in Haskell (versus arrays in C++), so you could likely do better, though I'm not sure it's worth the trouble.

Comment: Nice. On my machine, leaving off the bang pattern and forcing in the return (as in ```| otherwise = k3 `seq` (k3,'1':nsx2) where k3 = k2+k1+1```) makes it a tiny bit faster still.